# How do I open the Drawer when I hit back button

Tags: android

I am using google's default navigation drawer activity. in the menu of the drawer, I added added menu items that when clicked open other activities (not as fragments). These activities have the MainActivity as parent, which has the drawer. The Activities have the back button in the toolbar. When this back button is pressed, the app just goes back to the mainactivity with a closed drawer. How can I have the drawer opened whenever the back button is pressed in the child activities.

I know this could be easily solved by having the other activities be fragments, but that is not what I am going for.

Comment: Usually the **back button** is used as a BACK button. Opening the navigation drawer by clicking it is not an usual android UX. Your users will not be happy at all!

Answer (score 0):

You can ovveride onBackPressed() inside the activity(s) whose parent is MainActivity. And pass a value using a key value pair and check the data inside onCreate of the MainActivity using bundle and then openDrawer inside MainActivity as follows

Inside you ChildActivity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ChildActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("openDrawer", true);
    startActivity(intent);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

And then inside onCreate of MainActivty.class

```
private boolean openDrawer = false;
@Override
protected void  onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    Bundle bundle = getIntent.getExtras();
    if(bundle != null) {
        openDrawer = bundle.getBoolean("openDrawer");
    } 

    if (!openDrawer) {
        // Do other stuff and don't open drawer
    } else {
       //Open drawer login goes here
    }  
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error with the Bundle bundle = getIntent.getExtras;

Comment: Can you please post the logcat in your question ?